# Custom Paint Button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-painting

I'm trying to make a collection of hexagonal buttons in my flutter app, but I can't get it working.

I've tried a couple different things with CustomPaint and the ClipPath class, but my widgets either don't render correctly or don't detect any input. Does anyone have some advice on what the best practices to do here would be? Here's something I've tried:

```
        Container(
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: CustomHexagonClipper(Offset(0, 0), hexagonRadius),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => print("Button clicked!"),
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: HexagonPainter(Offset(0, 0), hexagonRadius),
              ),
            )
          ),
        ),
```

CustomHexagonClipper is a CustomClipper that draws a hexagon shape and HexagonPainter is the CustomPainter class I'm using.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include your `HexagonPainter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ShapeBorder for CustomBorder, just handle the path
. this ShapeBorder can be used on many widgets like Container, Material, InkWell....

Shape

```dart
class HexagonShape extends OutlinedBorder {
  @override
  OutlinedBorder copyWith({BorderSide? side}) => this; //todo

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return getOuterPath(rect);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(rect.left + rect.width / 4, rect.top);
    path.lineTo(rect.right - rect.width / 4, rect.top);
    path.lineTo(rect.right, rect.top + rect.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(rect.right - rect.width / 4, rect.bottom);
    path.lineTo(rect.left + rect.width / 4, rect.bottom);
    path.lineTo(rect.left, rect.top + rect.height / 2);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // TODO: implement paint
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

```dart
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  decoration:
      ShapeDecoration(shape: HexagonShape(), color: Colors.red),
),
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: HexagonShape(),
    fixedSize: Size(100, 100),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Center(
    child: Text(
      "Hello",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]